# How to rename react file without breaking the server?

Tags: reactjs

When i am tying to rename a file in React the Node package manager server show error that file not found.Even if i restart Node package manager it still shows it. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: What error does it show? Did you update all references to the file?

Comment: Please add the error message and the relevant parts of your package.json